# Angular 7: mat-card overflows mat-grid-tile when using a large image as mat-card-image

Tags: css, angular, layout, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using `mat-grid-list`. And each of its `mat-grid-tile` contains a `mat-card` which has header, image, content and action sections.

When a large image is used as `mat-card-image`, it expands the size of `mat-card` and causes it to overflow the container of its parent `mat-grid-tile`.

How can I make the `mat-card` to never overflow the container of `mat-grid-tile` even when a large image is used in its `mat-card-image` tag?

Stackblitz: [Stackblitz Mock Demo](https://angular-oesrxh.stackblitz.io)

Comment: can you share a stackblitz for this?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: https://moybqenxvmnr.angular.stackblitz.io

Comment: no mat-grid used here... this is the demo stackblitz from the mat-card

Comment: Does this work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oesrxh